# VB.NET - LINQ - dbContext - Where - Letter is not declared error. Trying to update single record

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm in the process of writing an update code to update user information on an asset used for a project I have.  The code is below...

```
AlteredUser = dbContext.Assets.Where(c >= c.ParentAssetID = ParentAssetId And c.AssetDecription = "USER").SingleOrDefault()
AlteredUser.AssetName = UserName
dbContext.SubmitChanges()
```

I'm getting an error message saying " 'c' is not declared ".  I've seen several examples of how to use the where clause within dbContext, and all of them use a letter as LINQ normally does.  I cannot figure out why it is erroring out for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>=` is a comparison operator.

To create a lambda in VB, write

```
Function(c) c....
```